# Use tools override library to force usage

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I am getting following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':ui:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0] E:\DHIS2_IN\Android\dhis2-android-new-sdk\ui\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\23.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>           Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.recyclerview" to force usage

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you defined the min sdk to be 1 although you can't define a minimal sdk lower than 7. You can even see that if you read the error good enough! I always advise you to really read the whole error twice before posting here

Comment: I have declared Min sdk as 15

Comment: Have declared  <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.recycler view"/> also but it didnt worked

Comment: Okay maybe you should add some more informations on what you have already tried and about your setup to the post